# kafkaserver shutdown hangs indefinitely on unit tests (kafka upgrade from 0.8.1.1 to 0.8.2.0)

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

We are recently upgrading from kafka 0.8.1.1 to 0.8.2.0. Our integrating tests are failing as the tests hang on kafkaServer.shutdown() indefinitely

These are my broker settings with

```
Properties brokerProps = new Properties();
brokerProps.put("zookeeper.connect", "127.0.0.1:8888");
brokerProps.put("port", "9092");
brokerProps.setProperty("num.partitions", "10");
brokerProps.setProperty("broker.id", "1");
brokerProps.setProperty("log.dirs", "some log dir");
brokerProps.setProperty("advertised.host.name", "127.0.0.1");
KafkaConfig config = new KafkaConfig(brokerProps);
```

This is the stack trace that i am seeing

```
 ERROR [kafka-network-thread-9092-0] kafka.network.Processor - Closing socket for /127.0.0.1 because of error
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at kafka.api.PartitionDataSend.writeTo(FetchResponse.scala:68) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.MultiSend.writeTo(Transmission.scala:101) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.api.TopicDataSend.writeTo(FetchResponse.scala:125) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.MultiSend.writeTo(Transmission.scala:101) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.api.FetchResponseSend.writeTo(FetchResponse.scala:231) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.Processor.write(SocketServer.scala:472) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:342) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

Comment: Are there exceptions in the consumer side?

Comment: yes. but it in our implementation of the consumer.. which i don't think affects the shutdown. Its failing on trying to connect to zk as zk has been closed

Comment: the kafka network processor is still running when the shutdown has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found of what the issue was. We were shutting down ZK before we were shutting down the kafkaserver. KafkaServer waits indefinitely trying to get a connection to the zkClient. 
   Changing the order worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a threaddump with [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) and analyze the output. Look for blocked threads or runnable threads, which are in native calls like socket or file operations. Then check the source code of the problematic threads.